# How to Count Unique Intersection of Field of Data Based on Another Field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

So, I have an index that has documents that contain 2 fields named `id` and `target_id`. Every document could have the same `id` or same `target_id` or both but there are only 2 unique `target_id`. Let say my index contains documents like this:

```
{"id": "123", "target_id": "001"}
{"id": "123", "target_id": "002"}
{"id": "124", "target_id": "002"}
{"id": "123", "target_id": "001"}
{"id": "125", "target_id": "001"}
{"id": "126", "target_id": "002"}
{"id": "126", "target_id": "002"}
{"id": "124", "target_id": "002"}
```

What I want to get is to count how many unique `id` that:

1. Has `target_id` `"001"` but not `"002"` (in the example there is only one `id` which is `"125"`)
2. Has `target_id` `"001"` and `"002"` (there is only one which is `"123"`)
3. Has `target_id` `"002"` but not `"001"` (in the example there are two `id`s which are `"124"` and `"126"`)

If this is impossible, at least I wanna get how many unique `id` that has `target_id` `"001"` and `"002"`.

Comment: Can you provide your mapping?